# Probability of Multiple Random Variables

Tags: statistics

Let $X_1$,$X_2$,$X_3$,$X_4$ be independent standard normal random variables and $Y=X_1^2+X_2^2+X_3^2+X_4^2$. Find the probability 
that $Y\leq 3$.

I thought that you would be using some kind of expectation, but I'm unsure how to proceed with that given that there are four random variables. Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question was asked the other day, so this might be a duplicate. In any case, you must observe that 
$$
     Y
\sim \chi^2_4
$$
see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution).

**UPDATE**

As requested in the comments, here is some more detail: using the formulae found in the link above, you see the density is 
$$
  f_Y(y)
= \frac{1}{4} y e^{-y/2}, \quad y \geq 0
$$
and the distribution is
$$
  F_Y(y)
= \frac{\gamma(4/2,y/2)}{\Gamma(4/2)}
= \int_0^{y/2} t e^{-t}dt
= \left( -te^{-t} - e^{-t} \right)^{y/2}_0
= 1-\left(\frac{y+2}{2}\right)e^{-y/2}.
$$
So 
$$
        P[Y \leq y]
=       1-\left(\frac{3+2}{2}\right)e^{-3/2}
\approx 0.44217.
$$

Comment: I am still confused

Comment: Okay, I've added more detail

Comment: A lot of books have $\chi^2$ tables in the back.